# Self-Hosted Agent Azure PowerShell (Core) - Module Not Found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I'm running a Self Hosted Windows Agent in Azure DevOps. I have installed PowerShell Core 6.2.3 and as the Administrator installed the Az module so that it is available to all users.

When I run a build using the Azure PowerShell task (V4) - marking as "Use PowerShell Core" and the "Latest Version" of Azure PowerShell I receive the following message:

```
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
Version      : 4.159.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [Learn more about this task](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613749)
==============================================================================
Added TLS 1.2 in session.
Disconnect-AzureRmAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
##[warning]Run Connect-AzureRmAccount to login.
##[error]Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' with Version: ''. If the module was recently installed, retry after restarting the Azure Pipelines task agent.
```

If I run the script on a Hosted Agent it works fine. I can't work out why it fails. I assume it is something different in the profile or environment that the build agent runs under - but I'm not sure how to check this.

On the build agent if I open a PSCore window and run:

```
Get-Module Az -ListAvailable
```

It finds the module correctly.

Comment: Have you restart your machine?

Comment: Yes several times!

Comment: You can try to switch to version 3.0 of the task to see if the problem go away. Please refer to this similar [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/818578/could-not-find-the-modules-azaccounts-with-version.html)

Comment: @Hugh V3 uses AzureRM and does not support PowerShell Core - of which I need both! I think the "Use PowerCore Core" checkbox does nothing (on Windows at least) and it is trying to execute it using Windows PowerShell.

Comment: Looks simliar to this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/670768/azure-devops-azure-powershell-task-wont-use-powers.html

Comment: I don't think that links resolves it. It says raise a ticket against PS Core. But I can't see how or why. To me it looks like the task ignores the "Use PowerShell Core" tick box. I see on GitHub there is a V5 version of this task now, but I do not know how to install it (it looks preview): https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShellV5

Comment: If you also install AzureRm modules on your machine, you need to uninstall AzureRM modules. It is a recommendation that Az and AzureRm modules both must not be installed on the same machine. You can refer to this point in this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11656)

Answer (score 1):

The DevOps Agent is most likely running as a different user and the Az modules have not been installed for that user. Assuming the agent is running as a service, you can check the user by running `services.msc` and look for "Azure Pipelines Agent", "VSTS Agent" or "vstsagent.[orgname].[agentname]" [1].

Run `Get-Module Az -ListAvailable` to see where the modules have been installed. Modules under `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules` have been installed for all users [2].

You can install the modules for all users with:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope AllUsers
```

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#run-as-a-service

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-7.1#parameters